# How to use JavaFX in jdk11?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am a beginner programmer and now I want to start GUI applications in java.(as I previously worked on java too). I started reading some books on FX but its not compiling on JDK11 .. Do I need to use jdk8 or is there any way i can do it on jdk11 too?

Comment: why not https://openjfx.io/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaFX has become unbundled from JDK11 (both Oracle's official JDK and OpenJDK). In order to use JavaFX with JDK11, you'll have to download the standalone [JavaFX11 runtime](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/).

Comment: What do you mean by "unbudled" ?

Comment: @FaizanAhmad it no longer comes with JDK. They also removed JavaEE stuff that was there before. JavaFX wasn't part of JavaSE standard anyway. Read more: https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-11-migration-guide/

Comment: Oracle is attempting to streamline Java by stripping away anything that they don't consider "core functionality." JavaFX is one of those non-core things. The idea is that Oracle wants to rev the JDK more frequently, so they don't want to have to bring JavaFX, JavaEE, etc. up to date every time as well.

Comment: How to install this unbundled package, on windows?

Comment: @laraflow Please do not comment on old answers in order to ask related, but distinctly different questions. Instead, post your question (assuming it's on topic for this site) as a question of its own. Stack Overflow operates in a Q&A format. It is not a free-flowing conversation. Also, Google is your friend -- use it.